# PHP get file extension from image url not ended in .ext

Tags: php, image

pathinfo() works fine only when the extension is present.

```
WORKS FINE:

$sourceUrl = "site.com/image.png";    
$photoExt = pathinfo($sourceUrl, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

.

```
NOT WORKING

$sourceUrl = "www.gravatar.com/avatar/d9d3bffa0ca503c495b2461881688467?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG";    
$photoExt = pathinfo($sourceUrl, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

I couldn't see solution on how to get file/image extension when the source doesn't  ended on it's file type.

Any solution?

Comment: And what would be the extension of that url?

Comment: @machineaddict if you visited the image link and download it, you will see that its file type is jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `pathinfo` to get extension of file without extension.

For this remote file we only know what's the content-type of this image (`Content-Type => image/jpeg`). But this content-type can have jpg or jpeg extension and we simple don't know what's this file real extension so PHP cannot determine it either.

If you want to simple check image type of this resource you can use:

```
echo exif_imagetype('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d9d3bffa0ca503c495b2461881688467?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG');
```

It will return 2, what is `IMAGETYPE_JPEG` according to documentation but still you won't know anything about real file extension.

Answer (score 2):

When you fetch the file look at the Content-Type header. It will be `image/[something]`.

That is the filetype and you can derive an extension from that.